# Agregar Content-Type a Axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

Como agrego `aplication/json` a `axios`

he intentado de estas formas pero ninguno funciona

```
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    window.axios.defaults.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
```

y tambien

```
            axios.get(`${uris}/lkvehiculo`, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                }
            }).then(res => this.setState({ lkvehiculo: res.data })),

/*********************************************************************/
            axios.get(`${uris}/lkvehiculo`, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json;',
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                }
            }).then(res => this.setState({ lkvehiculo: res.data })),
```

la peticion siempre se envia como `text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: Quizás el `Content-Type` de la uri sea `text/html`. Osea que en el documento **lkvehiculo** añadiste la cabezera `Content-Type: text/html` y por eso la cabezera de la respuesta sea `text/html`

Comment: Recuerda que estas haciendo una petición **GET**, no estas enviando un **POST**

Comment: lo mando de tipo **GET** porque es una lista que se rendriza en **Laravel** y el `type` de request es el unico switch para devolver un `view o array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema es que el cuerpo (`body`) de tu solicitud está vacío (no hay cuerpo), por lo tanto `axios` pasa olímpicamente del valor que estableces en tu cabecera, ya que no hay contenido (`Content`).

**SOLUCIÓN**

Una posible solución, si lo que deseas es enviar la solicitud con esa cabecera (aunque se trata de una petición tipo `GET` sin parámetros ni cuerpo) sería enviar un objeto vacío a modo de *contenido*.

La utilidad de esto dependerá de lo que estás tratando de lograr con tu solicitud.

Tendrías que hacer la misma de esta forma (por ejemplo):

```js
axios.get(`${uris}/lkvehiculo`, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  },
  data: {} // envío un cuerpo (aunque sea un objeto vacío)
}).then(res => this.setState({ lkvehiculo: res.data })),
```

De esta forma tu solicitud será hecha con la cabecera establecida.